# R scatter plots for above 1,000 unique parameters

Tags: r, loops, scatter-plot

I have a `data.frame` `Set` and I used the following commands to plot scatter plots of each column (y axis) against the `TmSlope`.

```
pdf("C:Desktop/Documents/RL/Lyzozyme/plots")
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in seq(1, length(Set),1) ) { 
  plot(Set$Tm.slope,Set[,i],xlab="Tm.slope",type="p",col="red",ylim=c(-0.05,50),xlim=c(0,6))
}
dev.off()
```

My question is how can I make sure that for each plot the y axis is labeled with the unique column name?

Comment: Where do the "1000 unique parameters" fit in?

Answer (score 1):

To label an axis, use : `ylab` in the `plot` function.

I do not know what you exactly use as data but you could do :

```
plot(...,ylab=names(Set)[i])
```